# Is it possible to use formulas in a text box in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm wondering if it's possible to set up a text box in Excel so that it displays the output of a formula.

For example my text box might contain:

"The sum of 5 + 5 is `=sum(5,5)`"

Where the part with the formula would simply display **10**.

Comment: It is possible using VBA. Is that allowed?

Comment: I added an answer using a helper cell. It looks like you have a typo in saying the result of `SUM(5, 5)` is 5; it should be 10.

Comment: @davidmneedham, I'd prefer to do this without VBA. I think I'd ask the question in stack overflow if I were looking for a VBA solution, but thanks for checking. I'm guessing it's useful to specify the solution type (VBA/non-VBA) in the question. I'll keep that in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text box values can be set to be equal to a cell reference. You can use a helper cell to show your formula.

Set cell A1 to be `="The sum of 5 + 5 is " & SUM(5, 5)`

Then insert a text box. Within the formula bar, enter `=A1`

[image: Example]

**To add a text box with multiple lines**

A text box can only contain a single cell reference, but the helper cell may contain linebreaks using `CHAR(10)` (the linebreak character in Windows).

For example, the following formula will result in a text box with two lines:

```
="The sum of 5 + 5 is " & SUM(5, 5) & CHAR(10) & "The sum of 3 + 3 is " & SUM(3, 3)
```

[image: Linebreak example]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is it possible to put a newline character `\n` or something like this to allow the text box to contain two formulas (i.e. cell references) on two separate lines?

Comment: @macsmith See the additional example in the edit to my answer.

Comment: Awesome. This is great. I'm trying not to get too excited, lol. One last question though. Is it possible to format only the first part of the line (e.g. bold), but not the second part? Currently, any formatting I apply to the cell (using options from the ribbon), applies to everything and I can't modify the contents of the text box directly.

Comment: @macsmith I believe the only way to adjust parts of a text box formatting would be to use VBA (likely the `Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Bold` property). I suggest asking a new question if you need help with that.